# Use Variable in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a variable in my regex pattern. This variable will always change and never be the same.

Whenever I try to use it in the pattern it gives me an error. Since the variable im using is a path, it sees "\" as an escape sequence and whichever letter as well so for example "c:\users" would be seen as "\u" which gives me an error.

I was wondering if there is any way around this, like i said this variable is always changing and hard coding any values wouldn't work.

Here is my existing code for the regex pattern:

```
public static Boolean validateFilePath(String dstPath, String newFileDstPath)
{
   Boolean blnflag = false;
   Match m = Regex.Match(newFileDstPath, @""+ dstPath + "");

   if (m.Success)
   {
      blnflag = true;
   }
   return blnflag;
}
```

Comment: What about `dstPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\")`?

Comment: Are you even using any regular expression patterns in `dstPath`?  If not just use String.Contains so you don't have to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Regex.Escape method?  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you [READ THE DOCUMENTATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will discover the method [`Regex.Escape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will probably serve your purpose.

Some other notes:

- Why are you doing this: `@"" + dstPath + ""` That resolves to `dstPath`, unchanged.
- Why are you trying to use regular expressions for something that might be better addressed by using [`string.StartsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) and/or the method and properties of [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)